# jQuery Add Dynamic Table with Clickable Rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm somewhat new to jQuery, and I see examples of how to add clickable dynamic TRs to existing tables, but how can I add an entirely new table dynamically that has clickable TRs?

My HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="containing"><div id="results"></div>
```

My jQuery code, which POSTs the input and returns the new HTML table into the Results div:

```
$("#containing").on("keyup", function() 
{
 $.post("http://URL.com/search.php", { searcher: $(this).val() },function(data, textStatus) 
 { 
  $("#results").html(data);
 });
});
```

Search.php returns the following format:

```
<table id="resultantTable"><tr><a href="..."></a><td></td></tr></table>
```

... and additional jQuery code that's supposed to let me click the new table rows, which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 $("#resultantTable").on('click','tr',function()
 {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) 
  {
   window.location = href;
  }
 });
});
```

This jQuery code works for tables that load up with the document, but I cannot get the TRs to be clickable in the dynamically-created table that is returned from search.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the listener on a parent. example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#resultantTable tr', function(e){
  //ToDo...
});
```

Comment: This works beautifully, @tenhsor, except now my next chunk of code, the actual redirect from the embedded anchor in the TR, fails, since it's referencing $(this), and $(this) is no longer the actual row being clicked:
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href) 
    {
     window.location = href;
    }

How can I redirect the page to the link that's in the TR anchor that was clicked?

Comment: $(this) It should gives you the element that you clicked, can I see the resultTable format to see what is going on

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. In other cases, I'm able to anchor outside of a `<td>`, like: `<tr><a></a><td></td></tr>`.

For dynamic content, though, I have to anchor inside a `<td>`, like `<tr><td><a></a></td></tr>`. 

Not sure why that is, but it's working. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour happens because you set the event listener on all existing table, but when you dynamically create a table it does not have this listener. 
One way to fix this is to set the event listener on the newly created table on creation, but the way I do it is putting the event listener on a parent element which I know exists on document load (like body)

```
$('body').on({
    click: function(){
    ...
    }
}, '#resultantTable tr' )
```

Comment: This works perfectly, @OryanM, except now that I'm referencing a parent, how can I pull the anchor link out and redirect to it? The code I use on the other tables that exist on document loading have direct id names that aren't dynamic, so I can reference them by calling $(this). 

How can I redirect to the clicked TR in your "..."? Thank you!

Comment: $(this) will give you the element, then you can find and redirect to the a link nested inside it with window.href = $(this).find('a')

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the events was registered before the ajax content exist. (resultantTable does not exists the first time the DOM is loaded)

Try to add your function after $("#results").html(data);

it is a good practice, in your ajax call, that you listen on success/error events

Add the render and click jobs inside the success events.

See jquery documentation about that